# Windows application and website server communication

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my project I have created an application in windows using C#.
In the application I want to connect to my web server (or domain) and send a request to it,
and then in my web server I want to create a page or a web application to answer the request !

For example I want to send a request like 'Name?' from my windows application,
then I should be able to get the request text in my web server (www.mydomain.com) and answer properly. (e.g. 'jack').

How should I do this !?
should I use chat server? (if so, isn't there any easiest way?)
Any other Idea?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend taking a look at the .net WebRequest class.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [web service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service), I think that is what you want. Here is code project link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16325/NET-Web-Services-Concepts. And you should also take a look at [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456779.aspx), that would also help you.